# Como condicionar a visualização de uma lista de Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tentei utilizar um `if` para condicionar a visualização de uma lista de `Widgets`:

```
children: <Widget>[
  if (condicao == true) 
  {
    Widget(),
    Widget(),
  }
],
```

> The element type Set < Widget > can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Me parece que na parte de design o flutter não interpreta a {} como escopo como no código em `Dart` puro.

Comment: Já tentou algo como `[...] children: condition ? getMyWidgetsArray() : [], [...]`? Se o problema é só como o Dart interpreta, isso deve resolver. Não conheço o Dart, então isso é só um pseudocódigo, não sei se isso é compátivel com a linguagem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode abrir um novo contexto dentro de uma lista, no caso, abrir `{}` em um `if` ou `for`. Mas, isso pode ser feito através do [operador](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) de `spread`, ou `...`:

```dart
void main() {
  final insert = true;

  final list = [
    'a',
    if (insert) ...[
      'b',
      'c',
      'd',
    ],
    'e',
  ];

  print(list);
}
```

Irá imprimir:

> [a, b, c, d, e]

Exemplo no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/b4bc642f4bd3961f85dcf4bce2d7a115).